# Why is clutter_actor_animate affecting the wrong actors?

Tags: c, clutter

I've been playing around with Clutter, using [this tutorial](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/clutter-beginners-tutorial) as reference, and am trying to animate three groups, each containing a colored rectangle. I am trying to use the `clutter_actor_animate` method used in the tutorial. If I animate just one of the three, it works; however, if I try to animate two or more groups, the first animation seems to apply to all animations. Why is this? Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
clutter_actor_animate (group_red, CLUTTER_EASE_OUT_SINE, 500, "x", 0-width, "y", 0, NULL);
clutter_actor_animate (group_green, CLUTTER_EASE_OUT_SINE, 500, "x", 0, "y", 0, NULL);
clutter_actor_animate (group_yellow, CLUTTER_EASE_OUT_SINE, 500, "x", width, "y", 0, NULL);
```

Where `width` is a gfloat containing the value `200`.

Answer (score 1):

I learned the answer: `clutter_actor_animate` requires floats for those values, so I needed to put `0.0` instead of `0`. The correct version is:

```
clutter_actor_animate (group_red, CLUTTER_EASE_OUT_SINE, 500, "x", 0.0-width, "y", 0.0, NULL);
clutter_actor_animate (group_green, CLUTTER_EASE_OUT_SINE, 500, "x", 0.0, "y", 0.0, NULL);
clutter_actor_animate (group_yellow, CLUTTER_EASE_OUT_SINE, 500, "x", width, "y", 0.0, NULL);
```